# why my htc status goes back to its rom defult settings after restart?

Tags: root-access, boot, htc-chacha

i have HTC status

i had unlock and root my phone
and also i created a 2nd ext3 partition which i linked it with Link2SD in order to improve internal memory.

then i installed a bunch of different apps

but then there sth odd had happened

once it goes off because battery didn't have enough charge , when i re start it again it come up with the basic settings just like it's the first time that the Rom is starts and all the customizations i made were gone
it runs a basic wizard that asks for basic settings and then when i check for those apps i had installed before they weren't there. also i check to see how much of the internal memory is occupied , i found it just 32M (or sth) just like there's no app installed on it

I'm wondering whether i could get back to all the customizations I've done on my phone or get all those apps back to my phone ?

it's very upsetting that every thing goes wrong this way... :-(

and i would be very thankful if you could clarify that what exactly goes on my phone
and how i can prevent this happen again.

the Rom which i had installed is custom build based on OTA update -> 1.57.415.3
Android version 2.3.5 - build (1.57.415.3)

Thanks for your help in advance!